# How to implement dp?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, combinatorics

I recently have encountered a question where I have been given two types of person: Left-handed and Right-handed (writing style). They all are to be seated in a class row and to avoid any disturbance their hands must not collide i.e. pattern may be like LR or LL or RR.
I tried using recursion (taking two branches of L and R for every seat) but number of computations would be very high even for a row size of 100. 
Somehow I need to implement DP to reduce the computations. Please suggest.

EDIT:
Actually there is a matrix (like a classroom) in which three types (L R B) of people can  be seated with no collisions of hand. I have to generate the maximum number of people that can be seated. Suppose I have a 2x2 matrix and to fill it with Left, Right and Both handed type of persons L=0, R=1 ,B =3 are given. So one valid arrangement would be Row0: `B R` and row1: `B -` where `-` means blank seat.

Comment: What is the question that that problem asks? You've only stated the constraints. If you just want some valid seating, just put all the left-handers on the left.

Comment: Question needs to seat maximum possible no of persons with given no of L and R. Also what wil ahppen if we have person who uses both hand simultaneously?

Comment: "Both hands" doesn't appear in your question, and I still see no problem with just putting all the left-handers on the left and right-handers on the right. There's nothing to optimize, it fills the entire row or seats all people, whichever comes first.

Comment: I have edited the question.. I was trying to fill in this matrix.

Comment: Ok good, now it's starting to look more like an actual problem.

Comment: I have edited the question.. I was trying to fill in this matrix. Like in 2x2 matrix with L=0 R=1 and B=3 i can fill with possibly 3 persons 2 B and 1 R. B shall seat in different rows. R will seat as B R configuration..

Comment: Please edit the question to include some clear examples.

Comment: I imagine that by now you've seen the Code Chef editorial solution? https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/77620/chcinema-editorial

Answer (score 1):

Actually the fact that you have a matrix doesn't make a difference in the solution you can transform it to an array without losing generality because each state depends on its left or right not its up and down. A bottom-up approach: In each state you have three things `L`, `B` and `R` , index of the seat you want to fill and its left person. Now we can fill the table from right to left. The answer is `dp[inedx=0][L][B][R][left_person=' ']`.

```
recursive [index][L][B][R][left_person] :
  if left_person = ' ' or 'L':
    LVal = recursive[index+1][L-1][B][R]['L']
  if left_person = ' ' or 'L' or 'R'
    RVal = recursive[index+1][L][B][R-1]['R']
  if left_person = ' ' or 'L':
    BVal = recursive[index+1][L][B-1][R]['B']
  NVal = recursive[index+1][L][B][R][' ']
  max(LVal, RVal, BVal, NVal) -> dp[index][L][B][R][left_person]
```

Of course this is not complete and I'm just giving you the genereal idea. You should add some details like the base case and checking if there is anymore person of that kind before assigning it and some other details.

Comment: I appreciate your help..    Here's my full pledged recursion code [http://ideone.com/caI01Z ]  But it does large no of computation and my time limit is 1 sec for n=100 m=100. So  its sure i have to use some more optimization to pass it...

Comment: Where is the problem source?

Comment: How is this practical with `1 ≤ N, M ≤ 10^8; 0 ≤ Z, L, R, B ≤ 10^16` ? (See the problem link, https://www.codechef.com/DEC15/problems/CHCINEMA)